# List of all elements of Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

Being a beginner, I have been trying to implement Binary Tree in python. And have been available to implement a lot successfully with only one problem that I am unable to return a list of all the elements (`traverse()`)in the binary tree. I am using two classes here, `Node` and `BinaryTree`.

## Node Class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Traverse method to return all  the elements in the binary tree.

```
    def traverse(self): #<-- Problem here
        tree_elements = []
        if self.left != None:
            self.left.traverse()

        tree_elements.append(self.value)

        #debug
        print(self.value, end=" ")

        if self.right != None:
            self.right.traverse()
        return tree_elements

    def addNode(self, node):
        if node.value < self.value and node.value != self.value:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = node
            else:
                self.left.addNode(node)
        elif node.value > self.value and node.value != self.value:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = node
            else:
                self.right.addNode(node)

    def search(self, val):
        if val == self.value:
            return "Found"

        elif val < self.value:
            if self.left != None:
                return self.left.search(val)
            else:
                return "Not Found "
        elif val > self.value:
            if self.right != None:
                return self.right.search(val)
            else:
                return "Not Found"
```

## Binary Tree

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addVlaue(self, val):
        node = Node(val)
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = node
        else:
            self.root.addNode(node)

     def search(self, val):
         if self.root == None:
             return False
         else:
             return self.root.search(val)

    def traverse(self):
         if self.root == None:
             return "no data"
        else:
            return self.root.traverse()
```

## Problem:

`traverse` method has to return all the elements in the binary tree, but i have been getting only first value of the tree.

example:

elements: 100 18 46 5 65 5 31 71 94 43 #input in the tree

output from tree:
5 18 31 43 46 65 71 94 100  #expected output

[100] #output from the tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tree_elements` list needs to go along the recurvise calls, collecting each node along the way. In other words, it must be passed as an argument to `traverse` calls (except when calling `traverse` for the root node).

Otherwise a new list is created and discarded in each traverse call (since you never do anything with the return value of `traverse` during its recursion), except for the top recursive call which returns the root element only.

Try this implementation:

```
def traverse(self, tree_elements=None):
    if tree_elements is None:
        tree_elements = []
   if self.left != None:
        self.left.traverse(tree_elements=tree_elements)
    tree_elements.append(self.value)
    if self.right != None:
        self.right.traverse(tree_elements=tree_elements)
    return tree_elements
```

Comment: understood the problem, Thanks!. One doubt though, while passing `tree_elements` as parameter in the function, are we appending the new elements in the very same list object?

Comment: Yes, the same list goes down the recursive calls and collects the nodes, then comes back up and is returned by the first `traverse` call.